# How to read real numeric values instead of formatted value using Apache XSSF POI streaming API?

Tags: apache-poi, sxssf

I use streaming POI API and would like to read the real value of a cell instead of the formatted one. My code which is below works fine but if the user doesn't display all the digit of a value in the excel sheet which is readed by my code, I've got the same truncated value in my result. I didn't find any solution in the streaming API - which is needed in my case to solve memory issue I had using the POI API without streaming.

```
    /**
     * @see org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler cell(java.lang.String,
     *      java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue, XSSFComment comment) { 
       useTheCellValue(formattedValue) 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are constructing the [XSSFSheetXMLHandler](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFSheetXMLHandler.html) you can provide a [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). So if you are creating your own `DataFormatter` this `DataFormatter` could give you fully access to the formatting issues.

Example of how this could look like by changing the `public void processSheet` of [the XLSX2CSV example in svn](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java?view=markup):

```
...
public void processSheet(
        StylesTable styles,
        ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings,
        SheetContentsHandler sheetHandler, 
        InputStream sheetInputStream) throws IOException, SAXException {
    //DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US) {
        //do never formatting double values but do formatting dates
        public java.lang.String formatRawCellContents(double value, int formatIndex, java.lang.String formatString) {
            if (org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil.isADateFormat(formatIndex, formatString)) {
                return super.formatRawCellContents(value, formatIndex, formatString);
            } else {
                //return java.lang.String.valueOf(value);
                return super.formatRawCellContents(value, 0, "General");
            }
        }
    };
    InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheetInputStream);
    try {
        XMLReader sheetParser = SAXHelper.newXMLReader();
        ContentHandler handler = new XSSFSheetXMLHandler(
              styles, null, strings, sheetHandler, formatter, false);
        sheetParser.setContentHandler(handler);
        sheetParser.parse(sheetSource);
     } catch(ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SAX parser appears to be broken - " + e.getMessage());
     }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a ticket on POI about this point : https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61858

It provides a first solution by changing the existing class.

This could be an interesting workaround even if the ideal solution should be to use a standard one.

Comment: To cite [PJ Fanning](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61858#c1): "If you look at the XLSX2CSV example in Poi, you will see that you can provide your own DataFormatter and with a custom DataFormatter, you could omit the number formatting and just represent the numbers in plain format."