# How to read Raw value rather then the formatted value from the excel sheet using POI library using XSSFReader class

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-2007

They are using the `XSSFReader` to read the sheet:

```
XSSFReader.SheetIterator iterator = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator)xssfReader.getSheetsData();
```

And then they are using override method:

```
@Override
public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue, XSSFComment comment) {
    parseCell(cellReference, formattedValue, currentRow, currentData, sheetName);
}
```

In this `formattedValue` is getting the value 1.12.

I need to get 1.1234 instead. How to get that?

I need to read the raw data.

Comment: Who is "they"? And what exactly are "they" doing? The method `cell` is from `XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler` and `XSSFSheetXMLHandler` always uses [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). This tries to format values as shown in Excel. If you don't want this, you either need to tell the `DataFormatter` what you want (`DataFormatte.addFormat`) or code your own sheet handler.

Comment: Thanks Axel for your answer, Yes cell method is used in XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler , but how can i override the cell method so that i can get the raw orginal value.

 ContentHandler handler = new XSSFSheetXMLHandler(styles, strings, new XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler() {

                @Override
                public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue, XSSFComment comment) {
                    parseCell(cellReference, formattedValue, currentRow, currentData, sheetName);
                }
            }, false
            );

Comment: You can't as `public void cell` already gets `String formattedValue` from `DataFormatter`.

Comment: so how can i use this cell method to read the unformatted/raw value so that i can send that value to parsecell method in cell method,

could you please send some sample code

Comment: is any other way to get the raw data using the existing funtionality like XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler()

Comment: Code your own sheet handler. Simple example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59134507/implement-memory-efficient-xlsx-reader-in-java-using-poi-with-xssf-and-sax-but-d/59153909#59153909 - based on https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api.

Comment: If the only problem is numerical value formatting, you can pass in a custom DataFormatter to the XSSFSheetXMLHandler and continue to user the SheetContentsHandler interface.

Just override the main formatRawCellContents(...) method to not format the value and return the raw value. e.g.

@Override
public String formatRawCellContents(double value, int formatIndex, String formatString, boolean use1904Windowing) {
    return Double.toString(value);
}

Comment: i found this comment, could you please say how to implement it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580500/how-to-read-real-numeric-values-instead-of-formatted-value-using-apache-xssf-poi/50585705#50585705